# Importing React-Native-Elements as an Object is Undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, import

I am having an issue using elements imported from the `react-native-elements` library.

I have installed the latest version of both XDE (and project is a new CRNA) and React-Native-Elements.

I then import the library with the following *which generates no errors*:

```
import RNElements from 'react-native-elements';
```

I attempt to use the element as follows:

```
<RNElements.Text h1>Heading 1</RNElements.Text>
```

Which generates the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeElements2.default.Text')

The interesting part is that I import both React Native and React Native Elements the same way, and I use their objects in the same way, but only React Native Elements throws an error.

Has anyone seen this error before?

**Update: this issue is not with any specific element, it is with the process of importing the library as an object.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import all of those element by

`import * as RNElements from 'react-native-elements';`

then use it: `<RNElements.Text h1>Heading 1</RNElements.Text>`

Answer (score 0):

Text is not in the react-native-elements components list. Check here the included components:
https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements

Comment: I should clarify, that it does not work with button either. I was working off of this list of components: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/text.html

Comment: Maybe just try to use like this:
`import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
<Button />;`

Comment: If I wanted to use the entire library as an object instead of importing every element individually, then this solution does not work. Is there a way to import it all as an object?

Comment: Ok, I will check your problem with the library import, however I thought the initial issue was with the `Text` element :)